# same table select friend request

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am writing a chat database.
If users are friends, then they have each other in the friends table, like user 1 and 2 or 1 and 5 in my table(see link). 
But I want to find out who sent the application as a friend. In this case, only one person stores the id of another person, like user 1 who sent request for user 7. 
I have table:

[image: friend table]
(only 3 column: idfriend, iduser, friend_id)

How i can select user id (friend_id) who sent request for friend?
If i chose user 1, then my sql must return this friend request:

|friend_id|

7

i try this:

```
select friend.friend_id from friend inner join friend as friends on 
friend.iduser != friends.friend_id and friends.iduser != friend.friend_id  
and friend.iduser != friends.iduser and friend.friend_id != 
friends.friend_id where friend.iduser = 1
```

but this select 7,2 and 5. Need only 7

Comment: field idfriend is auto increment. Ignore him

Comment: . . Your question is unclear.  Show your result set as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.friend_id from friend t
where t.iduser = 1 
and not exists (
  select 0 from friend
  where iduser = t.friend_id and friend_id = t.iduser 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qcJ9DJzSdBfQ5ZD5ErHXC/0).
Results:

```
| friend_id |
| --------- |
| 7         |
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you tell me what sql requset i should use for find friend friend, like user 1 - 2 and 1 - 5 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This code works for 1 user. If you want results for multiple users change `where t.iduser = 1` with something like `where t.iduser in (1, 3. 5)`

Comment: no, i mean how a can find all friends of friend 1, for example

Comment: `select friend_id from friend where iduser = 1`

Comment: If by friends you mean these ids that exist in both columns then instead of `not exists` use `exists`.

Comment: a little bit wrong. Users are friend only if user A have user B and user B have user A, like users 1 - 2 and 1 - 5 in my table. Friend for user 1 is: 2 and 5

Comment: Thanks!) i replace not exists on exists

Comment: If you remove not from not exists you get the correct result. See my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is the solution you are looking for:

```
select t1.iduser, t1.friend_id
from friends t1
where t1.friend_id not in
(
select t2.iduser
from friends t2
where t2.friend_id = t1.iduser
)
```

Comment: `select t1.friend_id
    from friend t1
    where t1.friend_id not in
    (
    select t2.iduser
    from friend t2
    where t2.friend_id = t1.iduser
    ) and t1.iduser = 1`    Thanks!)